# Using diff command in unix to find the difference

Tags: shell, unix

I have two text files (new.txt and old.txt) which contains the recursively navigated directories.

new.txt

```
338465485   16 drwxr-x---  26 encqa2   encqa2      16384 Nov 13 06:04 ./
338465486    4 drwxr-x---   4 encqa2   encqa2       4096 Sep 19 08:38 ./excalibur
338465487    8 drwxr-x---   3 encqa2   encqa2       8192 Nov 11 14:33 ./excalibur/data_in
338465488    4 drwxr-x---   2 encqa2   encqa2       4096 Nov  9 23:16 ./excalibur/data_in/archive
```

old.txt

```
338101011   40 drwxr-x---  26 encqa2   encqa2      36864 Nov 13 06:05 ./
338101012    4 drwxr-x---   4 encqa2   encqa2       4096 Dec 14  2016 ./manual
338101013    4 drwxr-x---   2 encqa2   encqa2       4096 Aug 25  2016 ./manual/sorted
338101014    4 drwxr-x---   2 encqa2   encqa2       4096 Aug 25  2016 ./manual/archive
338101015    4 drwxr-x---   4 encqa2   encqa2       4096 Aug 25  2016 ./adp
```

338101016    4 drwxr-x---   6 encqa2   encqa2       4096 Aug 25  2016 ./adp/0235

what I need is the only it provides me the directories , i.e

expected output after diff should be

```
./
./excalibur
./excalibur/data_in
./excalibur/data_in/archive
./excalibur/archive
./shares
./shares/data_in
./shares/data_in/archive
./shares/sorted
```

please provide me the command

Comment: please help me with the correct solution

Comment: If I understand correctly, one of your files has more (and different) data than the other and you want to list out the directories/files which are not present. right? The example file contents you have posted are same and the output you have listed as expected does not make sense with respect to you input files.

Comment: the question is, I have two version of codes, now i want to compare the two version folders, my approach was to recursilvely navigate the folders and subfolders by running **find ./ -type d -ls >>n.txt** , i run this command in both the folders and get the two text file. and then i applied diff in the output two text files, now I only want the directories, not the count and date modified

Comment: Try this `awk 'BEGIN{RS="\n"} {print $11}' new.txt > new_t.txt`

Comment: If you use the `-print` option instead of `-ls`, you will get only names and not the extra stuff you want removed.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to do get those lines from the two text files which are different, but from these lines you want to output only the directory names, not the full information.

If you do a

```
diff {old,new}.txt
```

the differing lines are marked in the output with either a '>' or a '<' in the first column, so you get the desired lines  by grepping for these characters:

```
diff {old,new}.txt | grep '^[<>]' | ....
```

Now you need only the file names. This is easiest if you know for sure that your pathes won't contain any space. In this case, you can, for instance, pipe your data into:

```
... | grep -oE ' [^ ]+$' | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | ...
```

If however the file names can contain spaces, you need to follow a different strategy. For instance, if you know that the number of characters in each line up to the file name is always the same, you can use `cut -c ....` to select the last portion of the line. Otherwise, you would need to process each line using a regular expression which describes the portion you want to throw away. I would use in this case Perl or Ruby, because I'm most familiar with this, but it can also be done with other tools - Zsh, awk, sed.

After this, you need to remove duplicates. These may occur for instance if a line differs between new.txt and old.txt not in the filename part, but in the file information part. This can be done by finally piping everything into

```
.... | sort -u
```